# MySQL comand for getting all results within radius and that match the same type

Tags: mysql, sql

So,

I've been arround the developers.google site and I wanted to add a feature but SQL ain't my strong.

So, using this formula :

```
SELECT id, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(37)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) 
  - radians(-122)) + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance 
FROM markers HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

We get the nearest 20 the customers id within a 25 miles radius, right?

I wanted to fetch all those customers that have a certain type (like - I have the column type and I want the nearest customers that are type 2 and are in that radius ).

Is this possible ?

Comment: Add after "ORDER BY distance" "ASC" or "DESC" and add after "FROM markers " a "WHERE customer='type1' " with a filter than you need

Answer (score 0):

id try this:

```
SELECT id, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(37)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) 
  - radians(-122)) + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance 
FROM markers
WHERE type = 2
GROUP BY id, distance
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

That is if your customer is in this table. otherwise, you need to do a join as this:

```
SELECT id, (3959 * acos(cos(radians(37)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) 
  - radians(-122)) + sin(radians(37)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance 
FROM markers
JOIN customer ON customer.id = markers.id
WHERE customer.type = 2
GROUP BY id, distance
HAVING distance < 25
ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use an UDF (in fact I do)

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION GetDistance (orgLat float, orgLong float, destLat float, destLong float)
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
       DECLARE dist INT;
       SET dist := ROUND(3959 *
                acos(cos(radians(orgLat) ) *
                cos(radians(destLat)) *
                cos(radians(destLong) - radians(orgLong)) + sin(radians(orgLat))
                * sin(radians(destLat))));
       RETURN dist; 
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```